# How does the time loop work?

Tags: plot-explanation, charmed

From the same movie as my previous question (Charmed), **Piper** has a power that freezes someone on the spot allowing her to do something undercover. She has done this in resturaunts, in her house, and to stop **Pheobe's** boyfriend from being killed by police (Pheobe used the power then), Pheobe used her magic to stop the flying bulets, and then she plucked them out of the air to prevent them from hitting him.

What I don't understand is how does it work and from the time loop's victim's perspective; how does the time shift in this way?

**Can someone give me an explanation for this as it has me stumped and I'm going around in circles trying to figure it out.**

Comment: Could you elaborate? Charmed is a *TV Series*, and IIRC, Phoebe does *not* have the ability to freeze. Only Piper.

Comment: As I recall, it started as *freezing time* and was retconned into *freezing molecules* or some such b.s.

Comment: http://charmed.wikia.com/wiki/Piper_Halliwell/Power_Development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think time just continues moving, she is only able to manipulate the molecules in people/things to stop them from moving (and later on make them move extremely fast), not time itself. There was the episode in which Dan Gordon dug up Leo's past and they (Dan and Leo) started fighting. Long story short, Piper froze them, unfroze Leo, had a conversation and told him to get back in place. You can clearly see that Dan is genuinely surprised and confused by Piper's sudden appearance (

). There is another episode (much later on in the series - purely from memory, as i last watched Charmed about 2 years ago) in which the sister's are arguing amongst themselves in i think it was Quake and they kept freezing and unfreezing the kitchen staff. This clearly confused the chef (as to how they kept jumping around the room).

With regards to how from the victims perspective, I think it would be similar to seeing a Demon blinking from place to place and being unable to explain it. Or similar to a blackout effect where they literally just lose time (as is allegedly experienced in UFO encounters).